# Keep relative position of annotations constant in relation to Donut Charts using Plotly (Python)

Tags: python, html, plotly

How do I keep the position of annotations constant relative to the position of the donut charts as screen resolution changes? In my situation the title centered within the donut hole in some cases and centered above the chart in others. I see that this an issue in the examples given by Plotly for the Pie Charts in subplots: https://plotly.com/python/pie-charts/#pie-charts-in-subplots

I am aware that this is almost certainly because I am using constants for my x and y coordinates but I don't know how to make them relative.

Roughly correct positioning:
[image: Positions looking pretty good]

Incorrect positioning after resizing window:

[image: Positions looking less good]

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

lst_abc = [153, 256]
lst_def = [1569, 724]
lst_ghi = [75618, 28971]
lst_long = [2, 5]

# Create subplots, using 'domain' type for pie charts
specs = [[{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}],
         [{'type':'domain'}, {'type':'domain'}]]

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, specs = specs)

# Define pie charts                    
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=[1,2], values=lst_abc, name='ABC'), 1, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=[1,2], values=lst_def, name='DEF'), 1, 2)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=[1,2], values=lst_ghi, name='GHI'), 2, 1)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=[1,2], values=lst_long, name='Longer Title Here'),
              2, 2)

fig.update_traces(hole=.4, hoverinfo='percent', textinfo='value')

fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    # Add annotations in the center of the donut pies.
    annotations=[dict(text='ABC', x=0.213, y=0.805, font_size=15, showarrow=False),
                 dict(text='DEF', x=0.787, y=0.805, font_size=15, showarrow=False),
                 dict(text='GHI', x=0.213, y=0.200, font_size=15, showarrow=False),
                 dict(text='Longer Title Here', x=0.82, y=0.46, font_size=15,
                      showarrow=False)])
fig.show()

with open('Current Stats.html', 'a') as f:
        f.write(fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```

Comment: DId you ever resolve this? I'm having a similar problem. No matter what coordinate system (xref and yref) I use, my annotations move around when the browser window is resized.

Comment: @Jussi Nurminen unfortunately I have not. Project deadline came up, I was creating digital handouts so my very poor workaround was to send everyone an HTML and PDF version. If things got too wonky with the HTML they could view the static PDF version.

Comment: This is hell ! ... it is supposed to be so simple, so straighforward ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I finally found a very easy solution !
You just have to use the `title` argument in the `go.Pie()` function, instead of `name`, and don't add any annotations in your `update_layout()` method

Comment: This works well for the "titles" in the middle of the doughnut. Adding a <br> and having the longer title in the donut hole is probably an acceptable work around for me so I'll marked this as an answer. Thank you